# Creating Acrobat Form Field Template

Tags: adobe, action, acrobat

I have an Excel workbook I create over 100 forms from. Their formatting is all the same, but the data is different. I'll use this to export these worksheets as individual PDFs. I want the PDFs to have form fields. I've created one PDF with the proper form fields I need. But getting the fields onto over 100 of these PDFs has proved challenging. I'd like to either automate this, or at least make it as easy as possible.

Currently, all I see as possible, is to open the template PDF, go to "Prepare Form," then click on all the form fields in the page menu to the right.

Then, I go to the PDF I want to copy them too, again, going to prepare form, then deleting all the fields it thinks I want to add.

Then go back to the template and copy all the form fields, then go back to the recipient form and past them there, moving them into place.

As you can see, this is not ideal for over 100 forms.

Any guidance would be very appreciated, thanks.